# CoffeeScript class - @ and this

Tags: coffeescript

I am confused with the usage of @ in CoffeeScript. I expected this to work but it doesn't -

```
obj=new class
 @x:5
 getX:->return @x

alert obj.getX() # undefined
```

On the other hand if we remove the `@` from `@x:5`, then it works somehow -

```
obj=new class
 x:5
 getX:->return @x

alert obj.getX() # 5
```

I thought @x is similar to this.x, but in the second case, I have not defined @x. Why does it work?

And when should I ever define `@x:5` instead of `x:5`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first instance, you're defining a "static" `x`, and a "non-static" `getX`. In the second instance, both member and method are non-static.

Had you named your class, you'd be able to access the first version's `x` as `ClassName.x`:

```
class TestClass
 @x: 5
 y: 6

obj = new TestClass

TestClass.x # 5
obj.y # 6
```

You should typically only be using `@` when you're inside a class method; inside a class declaration, the `this` to which `@` is referring can be thought of as the class itself.

Comment: So, `x` in the class declaration is an instance variable, but to refer to it in a method, I need to use `@x`. I find this slightly confusing.

Comment: This is how *most* languages behave. You don't use `this` until you're actually in a method being evaluated in the context of an object where `this` actually has a value. You'd use `getX: ->` to define a method, but *within* `obj`, you'd use `@getX()`. You wouldn't try to define `@getX: ->`...?

Comment: Shouldn't the instance variables also be connected with a `this` then? If syntax had been `@y: 6`, since `y` is tied to a `this`, it would be easier to make sense of.

Comment: `this` is *very different* at the point when you're declaring a class. There is no instantiated object yet, there is only the *class itself*. How can `this` refer to an object instance you have yet to instantiate?

Comment: Not sure I am getting it right. When I want `y` to be `6`, I want `y` of a particular instance to be `6`, isn't it?

Another question - would you know how I can access a static variable via a non-static method? For example how can I write an instance method that will return the `@x: 5` in your example code?

Comment: You'd write what I wrote: `ClassName.x`. Static variables are attached to the class itself, you access them through the class.